# How many ways two types of items can be given?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways, we can give $100$ type-$1$ items and $100$ type-$2$ items to $28$ people in such a way that each one receive at least one item and no one should get both type-$1$ and type-$2$ items.

My idea:

There are 28 people, so we can make the pairs $(1,27), (2,26) \cdots (27,1)$. That means, we are dividing $28$ people in such a way that sum of ordered pairs is $28$. Then the number of choices will be
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{27}\binom{100}{k} \binom{100}{28-k}.$$ Is it correct?

Comment: Not following.  If we had $2$ people instead of $28$, the answer would be $2$, right?  You give all the type-$1$ objects to one person and all the type-$2$ objects to the other. But you would appear to get $\binom {100}1\times \binom {100}1=10^4$, or am I misreading?

Comment: 1. You choose the $k$ who get the Type $1$ products. 2. You need to decide how many products you give to each one. 3. You have to repeat step 2 for Type $2$ products.

Comment: Once you know who the Type-$1$ people are, say, you can use Stars and Bars to count the ways to give them each some of the type-$1$ objects.  And so on.  I suggest working this out by hand in the case of $3$ people, maybe $4$ as well...so you have something to test your result against.

Comment: @lulu you are correct. My idea was to make the pairs of the type $(k,28-k)$ for $28$ people and then there will be $\binom{100}{k}$ choices for type-1 items and $\binom{100}{28-k}$ choices for type-2 items. But may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @UmeshShankar can you elaborate more?

Comment: My answer provides the details of Umesh Shankar's comment. Note that in addition to neglecting to choose which people get which items, you have also incorrectly applied stars and bars in your result.

Answer (score 1):

You need $\binom{28}{k}$ to choose $k$ people to get type-1 items. The remaining $28-k$ people will get type-2 items.

Using the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) formula $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for positive integers, the number of ways to distribute $100$ type-1 items to $k$ people so that each person gets at least one item is $\binom{99}{k-1}$, and the number of ways to distribute $100$ type-2 items to $28-k$ people so that each person gets at least one item is $\binom{99}{27-k}$.

All together, the total number of ways to distribute the items in the prescribed manner is $$\sum_{k=1}^{27}\binom{28}{k}\binom{99}{k-1}\binom{99}{27-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but was too long to be a comment either. Hope it helps.

##### HINTS

HINT: How many possibilities does one person have for **kind** of item?

HINT 2: Since each object is of the same type, what can it be restated as if only that object is being distributed?

> Stars and Bars

###### To think about: How to deal with running out?

Eg: First person gets 28 of type 1, then how do deal with it?